# YAML Error for CloudFormation file with !Equal & !Ref

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Getting an issue with YAML, for a CloudFormation file, which has been working perfectly till date and today it started giving an error that the file is not valid YAML for a few lines:

```
Conditions:
  Az2Enabled: !Equals [!Ref "AzCount", "2"]
  CreateStagingResources: Equals [!Ref "Environment", staging]
```

In the above example, the second line is giving an error, while the third line (although it is wrong) is not giving any error. The error that I get for the second line is:

```
unknown tag ! at line 95, column 38: ... Enabled: !Equals [!Ref "AzCount", "2"] ^
```

[image]

[image]

I am using the instructions from AWS, and have also downloaded the template from AWS only:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html
```

I have tried the YAML validators given online at the following URLS:

```
https://yamlvalidator.com/
https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator
https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml
```

If I remove the space between the : & !, it says the same is valid, but now gives an error for the line:

```
  Tags:
    - Key: ClientName
      Value:!Sub "${ClientName}"
```

Error is:

```
can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 108, column 37: Value:!Sub "${ClientName}" ^
```

This happens, if I remove the space between : & !Sub, and if I keep the space, it gives the above error!

Not sure, if I should convert it to the long format, tried following the format given at this link:

```
https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/be078deef45f8cb2e280ccc7af947392

Conditions:
  Az2Enabled: {"Fn::Equals", {Ref: "AzCount", "2"}}
```

The above format does not give the error, but will have to convert the whole file to this format then :-(

Has anyone encountered this issue and has a solution for it?

Comment: Are you getting errors submitting, or in a linter? I do believe the space after the `:` is required.

Comment: Both, when I ran it in AWS, it gave the error and so I checked the same on the Online Validators. The exact same file was working until yesterday. I have checked AWS document and they also say that space is required, but when I give the space, it gives the error, and when I remove it, the error goes away.

Comment: I would use cfn-lint to validate the file. It deals with some of the things unique to CloudFormation. Personally I only use the shorthand versions of the functions on the leaf nodes, so if I need a `Ref` inside an `Equals` I'll use `Fn::Equals` and `!Sub`. Also, I never use the JSON structure.

Comment: If I use the following format: Conditions:
  Az2Enabled: {Fn::Equals, [Ref: "AzCount", "2"]}, it works like a charm, but does that mean I need to change the whole file? Also, not sure as yet why it suddenly stopped working

Comment: I don't know that you *have* to change the file, I just find it easier. With regard to the YAML validators keep in mind that CloudFormation functions are not standard YAML, so many validators won't work. As for the "it suddenly stopped working", I have my doubts that something isn't different. AWS does break things at times, so it could happen, but it's more likely that there was something changed that you are missing, at least that's been my experience.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes really not sure about it, as I have used the same file I did yesterday from git and tried running the validator on it, and it still gives: aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body .\client_stack.yaml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: unsupported structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `!` in :

```
CreateStagingResources: Equals [!Ref "Environment", staging]
```

it should be:

```
CreateStagingResources: !Equals [!Ref "Environment", staging]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is an example line which is not giving an error. If I put the !Equals, instead of just Equals, it gives the same error as is mentioned.

Comment: @gagneet its still required, as you can't have plain `Equals`. So what is `AzCount` then?

Comment: Yes, totally get that. I have just placed it there as an example of what is working and what is not working. Sorry for the confusion, will separate the two, so that it is clearer